# How can I build a secure timer based button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

here's what I mean:

I have written up a simple timer that counts down from 5 minutes. At the end of 5 minutes, I'd like to display a button for my user to press. You can see my code at the end of this post.

I do not want the user to be able to press see the button before the timer runs out. I don't want the user to be able to go into the JS console and call "document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'block';" and have access to the button.

What are some ways I can do this, preferably entirely on the client side? Is there a way to do this entirely on the client side?

My backend is Ruby on Rails - if there's an easy solution using RoR, I'd be curious about that too. But frankly, I'd love to know if there's a fully client side way of doing this!

```html
<html>
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
      diff,
      minutes,
      seconds;

  function timer(timerIntervalId) {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    if (minutes == "00" && seconds == "00" && timerIntervalId != undefined) {
      clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
      document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (diff <= 0) {
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };

  timer();
  var timerIntervalId = setInterval(function() { timer(timerIntervalId) }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var timerLength = 60 * .15,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(timerLength, display);
};

</script>
<body>
  <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
  <div id = "button" style = "display: none;">BUTTON</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `preferably entirely on the client side` This would need some server side checking in all cases

Comment: If you don't want user to be able to show button from console , don't include the button and inject it after. You would at least need to move all this code out of global namespace and put it in a closure. Based on what you are wanting I doubt you can get 100% of what you want without server interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it bud, but there is no such thing as secure in javascript.  A user with a little knowledge will be able to do anything they want to your code.  But to attempt to give a suggestions

```
if (minutes == "00" && seconds == "00" && timerIntervalId != undefined) {
      clearInterval(timerIntervalId);
      ///document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'block';
      $("<div>").attr('id', 'button').appendTo($("#placeholder")).text("button")
}

<body>
  <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
  <div id="placeholder">

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this way the button doesnt exist until you create it at the end of the timer

https://jsfiddle.net/u3bae0uj/

Answer (score 0):

There is no fully client side solution. Because if yo implement this fully using client side, user can at some way change the timer (as you said, show button).

To be sure that 5 minutes will pass you will have to communicate with server, but can implement this using `ajax`.

At timer start you can call some action at server and start timer on server side, using `sessions` variable, when 5 minutes pass you execute ajax call on other action an check if 5 minutes have pass (this way you get 5 minutes, and user can not change it on client).

If 5 minutes have passed, you return html to user, inside html you return the button you want to show, so user can not inspect html, and set it visible, because server returns button after 5 minutes, and then user can click on it.